# Having trouble printing out the first two numbers in a dynamically allocated array, the other numbers work fine

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, random, dynamic-allocation

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

int* randomNumbers(int min, int max, int size);
int main()
{
    int min = 20;
    int max = 100;
    int size = 10;
    int* nums; 

    nums = randomNumbers(min,max,size); 
    cout << "***************"<<endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < size;i++)
    {
        cout << *(nums+i) << endl; 
    }


    return 0;

}


int* randomNumbers(int min, int max, int size)
{
    int* random = new int[size]; 
    unsigned seed = time(0); //time elapsed since Jan 1, 1970
    srand(seed);

    for (int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
        *(random+i) = rand() % ((max+1)-min) + min;
        cout<<*(random+i)<<" ";

    }

     cout<<endl;

    delete[] random; 
    return random;
}
```

So if I run this code in Xcode(Macbook), it works perfectly, however if I run this in Codeblocks(Windows) , the first two numbers printed from the main function are in the millions but the first two numbers printed from the randomNumbers() are within expected range. I don't understand why printing the numbers in the main function is changing the first two values? The rest are fine. I'm really inarticulate, feel free to ask questions on my question.

Comment: `delete[] random; return random;` This cant possibly be correct.

Comment: `a[i]` is far more readable (and less error-prone) than `*(a+i)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   delete[] random; 
   return random;
```

You are deleting your array!

Any access to your array after deleting it is Undefined.  Clean up the array when you are done with it.

Move the delete here:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < size;i++)
 {
     cout << *(nums+i) << endl; 
 }

 delete[] nums;
 return 0;
```

Comment: Do not recommend such for c++ code. There are way better method to achieve _dynamic storage allocaiton_.

Comment: Please spend a little time fixing the indentation.  If the OP can get it right you should be able to as well.